# Closing Parenthesis Recognition and Precedence of Operators In Infix to Postfix Stack Program C++

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-mta, infix-notation

I have an assignment in my Data Structures course where the C++ program calls a function named infixToPostfix, which reads an infix expression from standard input and writes the equivalent postfix expression to standard output.

However, I'm having difficulties with two logic errors at the moment:

1. My closing parenthesis isn't getting recognized in my program. When I attempt to pop the ')' out of the stack, it causes a segmentation error, crashing the program.
2. The precedence of operators during the conversion isn't in proper order. I'm guessing it's because my program is recognizing the operators to where each operator pops the previous one out of the stack, no matter what their precedence is.

My current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>    // Library used to store a stack of characters
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isOperator(char ch)    // Checks if character is operator
{
    if(ch == '^' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '+' || ch == '-')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool isOperand(char ch)     // Checks if character is operand
{
    // If not an operator or a parenthesis, then assume operand
    if(!isOperator(ch) && ch != '(' && ch != ')')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Retrieves weight of operators as per precedence
// Higher weight = higher precedence in operators
// Returns 0 for non-operators
int getWeight(char ch)
{
    switch(ch) {
        case '^': // exponents
            return 3;
        case '/':
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        default :
            return 0;
    }
}

string infixToPostfix(string expression)
{
    // Declare stack
    stack<char> op_stack;
    // Initialize postfix as empty string
    string postfix = "";
    
    for(int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++)
    {
        // Scanning each character from left.
        // If character is a delimiter, move on.
        if(expression[i] == ' ' || expression[i] == ',')
        {
            continue;
        }
        // If character is operator, pop two elements from stack,
        // perform operation, and push result back.
        else if(isOperator(expression[i]))
        {
            while(!op_stack.empty() && op_stack.top() != \
            getWeight(op_stack.top()) <= getWeight(expression[i]))
            {
                postfix += op_stack.top();
                op_stack.pop();
            }
            op_stack.push(expression[i]);
        }
        // Else if character is operand
        else if(isOperand(expression[i]))
        {
            postfix += expression[i];
        }
        // Parenthesis
        else if(expression[i] == '(')
        {
            // Push operator onto stack if empty
            op_stack.push(expression[i]);
        }
        else if(expression[i] == ')')
        {
            while(!op_stack.empty() && op_stack.top() != '(')
            {
                postfix += op_stack.top();
                op_stack.pop();
            }
            //op_stack.pop();
        }
    }
    
    while(!op_stack.empty())
    {
        postfix += op_stack.top();
        op_stack.pop();
    }
    
    return postfix;
}

int main() {
    string expression;
    cout << "Enter Infix Expression: \n";
    getline(cin, expression);
    
    // Displays inputted infix string and calculated
    // Postfix string
    cout << "Infix Expression: " << expression << '\n';
    cout << "Postfix Expression: " << infixToPostfix(expression) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter Infix Expression: 
(6+2)*5^8/4
Infix Expression: (6+2)*5^8/4
Postfix Expression: 6(2+5*8^4/
```

Where the correct postfix should be 62+58^*4/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: While you might able to solve your particular problem using hard to follow logic in your code, you will be better off using the proper abstraction to capture the input expression, [a binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).
Once the input is captured in a binary expression tree, it will be a lot easier to write it out as an postfix expression.